# How to click two checkboxes that appears before some text using Selenium xpath?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

A shown in below screenshot. I have two check boxes, before some text.

[image]

I need to click check boxes, by finding the text. Please guide me how to do this.

xpath :

```
<div class="ad-feature ng-scope">
<ng-include class="ng-scope" src="'view/enterprise-integration/activedirectory/sanctioned-setup.html'" style="">
<table class="ad-sanctioned-setup ng-scope">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<p>
<span class="description"> For Sanctioned Services, you can use multiple attributes when creating a unique key to identify a user. </span>
<div class="panel-data-preview ng-scope" ng-if="sanctionedEnabledOrDisabled[$index]">
<div class="data-scroll">
<table class="data">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="key in directoryUsersAttributesByControllerIndex[$index]" style="">
<td>
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="toggleAttributeSelection($parent.$index, key)" data-ng-checked="isAttributeAlreadySelected($parent.$index, key)">
</td>
<td>
<td class="ng-binding">lastLogoff</td>
```

Environment :

Python
Firefox browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following xpath to click on checkbox just before "lastLogoff" inside **Include as Key**

```
//td[contains(text(),'lastLogoff')]/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

Explanation -

```
//td[contains(text(),'lastLogoff')]
```

will locate the `<td>` tag with **lastLogoff** text

```
/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

will be use to move on`<td>` tag just before context node and also navigate to `<input>` tag of it.

Please use same way to click checkbox of under **Attribute to Send**

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Its perfectly working. is it possible to click only one checkbox before the text? I have a scenario to select only first checkbox sometime.

Comment: The above XPath will select only one check box just before **lastLogoff** if u have the requirement to sometime select another checkbox not current one So u just need to use xpath like `//td[contains(text(),'lastLogoff')]/preceding-sibling::td[2]/input`  this way

Comment: nice to here :)